# Leibniz rule and when we can apply this limit?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Firstly, I want to show this equality;

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\displaystyle\int_{y_0}^{y_1}f(x,y)\;dy\right)=\displaystyle\int_{y_0}^{y_1}f_x(x,y)\;dy$$

We can use ,limit definition of derivative;

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\displaystyle\int_{y_0}^{y_1}f(x,y)\;dy\right)=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{y_0}^{y_1}f(x+h,y)dy-\displaystyle\int_{y_0}^{y_1}f(x,y)dy}{h}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{y_0}^{y_1}(f(x+h,y)-f(x,y))dy}{h}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\displaystyle\int_{y_0}^{y_1}\dfrac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}dy$$

But ,I can't say basicly, I can't believe providing conditions of limits (I suppose) ;

$$=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\displaystyle\int_{y_0}^{y_1}\dfrac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}dy=\displaystyle\int_{y_0}^{y_1}\left(\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}\right)dy$$

If I can say this, this definetely equals to ;

$$=\displaystyle\int_{y_0}^{y_1}f_x(x,y)dy$$

Let this;

$$I=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{y_0}^{y_1}(f(x+h,y)-f(x,y))dy}{h}$$

Can we say this,if yes why?;

$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\left(I(x,y)\right)=I\left(\lim\limits_{h\to0}\right)$

The following equalition, under what conditions , will be true?

$\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=f(\lim\limits_{x\to a} x)$

Comment: What integral is it? Check dominated convergence theorem. Yes you need a dominating function or stronger continuity assumptions.